# Re-render react components after server sends new data

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a react application connected to a backend server via WebSockets, and I need to rerender specific react components after the server has sent new data.

I want to subscribe to key/value pairs in a store from any component that automatically triggers a rerender of all the subscribed components. How can I achieve that?

[Visualization of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IVos.png)

*(I'm entirely new to react & frontend development.)*

Comment: Just try to update the component state whenever the data is received

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I didn't understand how I should do that. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: have a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)